# Convert a data row to a JSON object

Tags: c#, .net, json, datatable

I have a `DataTable` which has only a single row and looks like

```
   America              |  Africa               |     Japan     |   
   -------------------------------------------------------------
  {"Id":1,"Title":"Ka"} | {"Id":2,"Title":"Sf"} | {"Id":3,"Title":"Ja","Values":{"ValID":4,"Type":"Okinawa"}}
```

The `DataTable` columns are America, Africa, Japan.

Now I want to convert the `DataTable` to JSON such that the JSON looks like

```
{
"America": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Title": "Ka"
},
"Africa": {
    "Id": 2,
    "Title": "Sf"
},
"Japan": {
    "Id": 3,
    "Title": "Ja",
    "Values": {
        "ValID": 4,
        "Type": "Okinawa"
    }
  }
}
```

My attempt was:

```
string js = JSonConvverter.Serializeobject(datatable);
var objType =  JObject.Parse(js);
```

But it didn't work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check Json.NET http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 25):

Assuming you are using [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net), there is a special built-in converter, [`DataTableConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DataTableConverter.cs), that outputs data tables in an [abbreviated format](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm) as an array of rows where each row is serialized as column name/value pairs as shown in your question.  While there is also [a converter for `DataSet`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DataSetConverter.cs), there is no specific built-in converter for [`DataRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx).  Thus when directly serializing a `DataRow` Json.NET will serialize all the fields and properties of the `DataRow` resulting in a more verbose output - which you do not want.

**The most straightforward way** to serialize a `DataRow` in the more compact form used by  `DataTable` is to serialize the entire table to a `JArray` using [`JArray.FromObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_FromObject.htm) and then pick out the array item with the same index as the `DataRow` you want to serialize:

```
var rowIndex = 0;

var jArray = JArray.FromObject(datatable, JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings { /* Add settings as required e.g. */ NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }));

var rowJToken = jArray[rowIndex];
var rowJson = rowJToken.ToString(Formatting.Indented);  // Or Formatting.None if you prefer
```

Since your table has only one row, `rowIndex` should be `0`.  More generally, if you don't know the index of a given `DataRow`, see *[How to get the row number from a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4502920/3744182)*.

This should work well for tables with just one row, but will not be performant in general.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ywqDCZ).

**Alternatively**, if the table has many rows but few columns, you could transform the row into a `Dictionary<string, object>` using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary), and serialize that:

```
var rowJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
        .ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => row.IsNull(c) ? null : row[c]), 
    Formatting.Indented);
```

As long as the number of columns is small, the performance should not be too bad.

Fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0qZ5WW).

**The most performant way** to serialize a row will be to introduce a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for `DataRow` that writes the row to JSON as an object:

```
public class DataRowConverter : JsonConverter<DataRow>
{
    public override DataRow ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, DataRow existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("{0} is only implemented for writing.", this));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, DataRow row, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var table = row.Table;
        if (table == null)
            throw new JsonSerializationException("no table");
        var contractResolver = serializer.ContractResolver as DefaultContractResolver;

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns)
        {
            var value = row[col];

            if (serializer.NullValueHandling == NullValueHandling.Ignore && (value == null || value == DBNull.Value))
                continue;
            
            writer.WritePropertyName(contractResolver != null ? contractResolver.GetResolvedPropertyName(col.ColumnName) : col.ColumnName);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new DataRowConverter() },
    // Add other settings as required.
};
var rowJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(row, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Notes:

- While it makes sense to serialize a single `DataRow`, it doesn't make sense to *deserialize* one since a `DataRow` is not a standalone object; it exists only inside some parent `DataTable`.  Thus `ReadJson()` is not implemented.
- [`JsonConverter<T>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_1.htm) was introduces in Json.NET [11.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/11.0.1).  In earlier versions inherit from [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm).

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p2JMxL).

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33400729/556770), you can use an `ExpandoObject` to quickly and pretty easily render a single row as JSON, as such:

```cs
var expando = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
foreach (DataColumn col in myRow.Table.Columns)
{
    expando[col.ColumnName] = myRow[col];
}
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(expando);
```

Answer (score 5):

Spelling? Shouldn't your call to the "SerializeObject" method be:

```
string js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datatable);
```

Also see a similar question on converting a [datatable to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979922/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-string-using-json-net).

Answer (score 2):

Like Gazzi said you should include the NewtonSoft.Json library it is included in Visual Studio.

To get an object similar to what you have described you should create a data model like Country.cs which would look like this.

```
[Serializable]
public class CountryModel {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public List<ValueModel> Values { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ValueModel {
   public int ValueID { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Create a helper function to convert your table data to these models. You can then serialize/deserialize data as need using the Newtonsoft Library.