# JSON.NET: How to serialize just one row from a DataTable object without it being in an array?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a database class that calls into a database and retrieves data. The data is loaded into a `DataTable` object with an `SqlDataAdapter`. I then want to take only the first row of data (in truth, the database will only ever return one row anyway) and convert it to a JSON string.

The problem is this: If I simply pass the `DataTable` into the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method, e.g. `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt)`, I get a JSON string but it is an array with one object. For example:

```
[ {"id":"1","value":"hi"} ]
```

The code on the other end that expects to receive this JSON does not want an array, it simply wants an object. So basically I need the above, but without the square brackets `[` and `]`. So the desired output is:

```
{"id":"1","value":"hi"}
```

The naive approach I am using right now is to just return `result.Substring(1,result.Length - 2)` to the caller. Assuming that the JSON object exists in a single array of just one object, this has the effect of stripping the `[` and `]` off the return text. But it seems like there should be a "proper" way to achieve this.

The most obvious thing would seem to be using the `Rows` property of the DataTable. However, if I try to do `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt.Rows[0])`, I don't get just the row, I get an entire collection of data about the state of the row, with one item being `Table` but which simply references the entire table, so in the event that more than one row occurred I would get all the rows, not just the one I desired.

The other approach I have tried is to round-trip into JSON from the entire `DataTable`. I serialize the `DataTable`, then parse the result into into a `JArray` so I can get the first value, then reserialize again. But this seems unnecessary.

Here's what trying to serialize a `Row` object gives me:

```
{
    "RowError":"",
    "RowState":2,
    "Table":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "value":"hello"
        }
    ],
    "ItemArray":[
        "1","hello"
    ],
    "HasErrors":false
}
```

Can I do this the "correct" way without just stripping the `[` and `]` off the string? In other words, can I get the data from one row of a `DataTable` as a single JSON object, not in an array, without roundtripping through JSON and back again just to pick it off the one-item array?

Comment: Duplicate, or just similar?  [Convert a data row to a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33399749/3744182).

Comment: Similar, but that answer seems to indicate there's no way to do it other than to roundtrip through a JArray.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to build up a `JObject` from the `DataRow`.  For example:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("id");
dt.Columns.Add("value");
dt.Rows.Add("1", "hi");

string json = new JObject(
    dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
      .Select(c => new JProperty(c.ColumnName, JToken.FromObject(dt.Rows[0][c])))
).ToString(Formatting.None);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{"id":"1","value":"hi"}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ndL1xu

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are only going to receive one row from the query/DataTable, in JSON.Net you can use a private setter that accepts the Table structure as a List and a public property that returns only the first row as an object like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class DataTableToModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Deserialize from DataTable, set ModelProperty from first row
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("Table")]
    private List<Model> ModelSetter { set { this.ModelProperty = value.FirstOrDefault(); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize Model
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("Model")]
    public Model ModelProperty { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Model that has id and value properties expected from DataTable
/// </summary>
public class Model 
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]       
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

To utilize this, you need to add your DataTable to a DataSet, and JsonConvert.SerializeObject the DataSet, then JsonConvert.DeserializeObject on the ModelProperty object like this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.TableName = "Table";
dt.Columns.Add("id");
dt.Columns.Add("value");
dt.Rows.Add("1", "hi");
ds.Tables.Add(dt);

var dsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);     
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTableToModel>(dsString);              
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.ModelProperty);
```

Here is a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8zC1fG) example.