# Serialize DataTable including RowError and "column errors"

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, ado.net

I want to serialize to JSON a .NET DataTable with RowError and column errors. I do something like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Col1");

dt.Rows.Add("A");

dt.Rows[0].RowError = "Test row error";
dt.Rows[0].SetColumnError(0, "Test column error");

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
```

The resulting JSON looks like this:

```
[{"Col1":"A"}]
```

No RowError or column errors information is included.

Is there a way to serialize DataTable with "error" information included?

Thanks.

Comment: I've never looked at it, but I presume that your serializer treats a datatable differently based on the indication that it does serialize the column value, which *isn't* a property but doesn't serialize things that are properties, which is something of a difference to other(normal) objects where props are serialized and nonprops aren't..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315700/json-net-how-to-serialize-just-one-row-from-a-datatable-object-without-it-being Looks helpful/interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to serialize to JSON a .NET DataTable with RowError and column errors

By default as you have seen, only the `ColumnName` and it's value are serialized. To include other properties that you want, you can do this by writing your own `JsonConverter` class, please see [Custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for more information. You'll need to have two converter's, one for the `DataTable` and another for the `DataRow`.

*Please note that each class will need to have this namespace: `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

**CustomDataTableConverter**

```
public class CustomDataTableConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => typeof(DataTable).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            DataTable table = value as DataTable;
            CustomDataRowConverter converter = new CustomDataRowConverter();

            writer.WriteStartObject();

            writer.WritePropertyName("DataRows");
            writer.WriteStartArray();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                converter.WriteJson(writer, row, serializer);
            }

            writer.WriteEndArray();
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }
```

**CustomDataRowConverter**

```
public class CustomDataRowConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => typeof(DataRow).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            DataRow row = value as DataRow;
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            writer.WriteStartObject();

            // Serializes the row error property
            writer.WritePropertyName(nameof(row.RowError));
            ser.Serialize(writer, row.RowError);

            foreach (DataColumn column in row.Table.Columns)
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(column.ColumnName);
                ser.Serialize(writer, row[column]);

                // Serialize the columns error description
                writer.WritePropertyName("ColumnError");
                ser.Serialize(writer, row.GetColumnError(column));
            }

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }
```

Now that you have the needed converters, here's how you use them in your case. Please note, I added another datarow to show the difference here.

```
 var dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("Col1");

 dt.Rows.Add("A");
 dt.Rows.Add("B");

 dt.Rows[0].RowError = "Test row error";
 dt.Rows[0].SetColumnError(0, "Test column error");

 dt.Rows[1].RowError = "Test row error B";
 dt.Rows[1].SetColumnError(0, "Test column error B");

 JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
 jsonSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new CustomDataTableConverter());
 jsonSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new CustomDataRowConverter());

 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

When this runs, my output looks like:

```
{
  "DataRows": [
    {
      "RowError": "Test row error",
      "Col1": "A",
      "ColumnError": "Test column error"
    },
    {
      "RowError": "Test row error B",
      "Col1": "B",
      "ColumnError": "Test column error B"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also something to remember, I didn't do the deserialize part of this, only the serialization part, but it's similar.