# Convert datatable to JSON and publish to PubSub row by row

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, google-cloud-pubsub

My flow is to take data from a SQL Server database (I'm using datatable) and then publish it to the PubSub (different message for each row). May someone help and suggest me the way in doing it?

I am using Newtonsoft.Json to convert to JSON.

This is my connection to the database:

```
    public DataTable RequestDataDB()
    {            
        SqlConnection database = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConn.DBConnectionString);
        database.Open();

        SqlCommand databaseCmd = new SqlCommand("Request_PubData", database);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(databaseCmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        database.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

This how I call it back and convert to JSON & publish it.

```
Console.WriteLine("Data to be Published Total : " + totalRows);
string jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RequestDataDB, Formatting.Indented);
string messageId = await publisher.PublishAsync(jsonOutput);
Console.WriteLine(jsonOutput);
await publisher.ShutdownAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your code is converting datatable to json and publishing. You can think of looping thru rows of datatable and publishing it individually

Comment: Beside question: why are you publishing row by row? There isn't more efficient thing to do?

Comment: Given your `DataTable` what do you want the JSON output to look like? [Convert a data row to a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33399749/3744182) might work or might not, we can't answer without knowing your specific desired output format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for all the tips & answer given. I'm more than grateful.
Actually, the requirement is to publish object by object `{} {}` instead of in sequence.`[ {}, {} ]`.
So here is the solution. Thank you so much guys.

```
 foreach (DataRow DataDBRow in RequestDataDB.Rows)
            {
                string json = new JObject(
                                         RequestDataDB.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                        .Select(DataDBColumn => new JProperty(DataDBColumn.ColumnName, JToken.FromObject(DataDBRow[DataDBColumn])))
                                        ).ToString(Formatting.None);
                Console.WriteLine(json);
                Console.WriteLine();
                string messageId = await publisher.PublishAsync(json);

            }
            await publisher.ShutdownAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
            //databaseConn.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Previous code:

```
string jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RequestDataDB, Formatting.Indented);
```